# Why QueryPerformanceFrequency is the TSC frequency divided by 1024, why not just TSC?

Tags: windows, winapi, performancecounter

Here is info from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Note  Cases might exist where QueryPerformanceFrequency doesn't return the actual frequency of the hardware tick generator. For example, in many cases, QueryPerformanceFrequency returns the TSC frequency divided by 1024;

But it isn't explained why frequency is divided.

Comment: Perhaps to fit into an integer. A CPU can have over 4GHz which cannot be represented by an Int32 value.

Comment: @AloisKraus: QPC and QPF return 64-bit integers.

Comment: Why does it matter?